# How to dynamicaly resize a button on stage in as2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a button on stage in a movie, the button ("clicker") is empty apart from the "hit" frame. The stage and button are 300x300 and i'm using swfobject to display the flash movie at 400x600 pixels. I have the following actionscript...

Stage.showMenu = false;
Stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
Stage.align = "TL";

clicker._x = 0;
clicker._y = 0;

clicker.onRelease = function() {
 trace("onMouseDown called");
 getURL(link_url, "_blank");
};

I want teh button to expand to fill the available stage space (which is 400x600 in this example) so i use the following...

clicker._width = Stage.width;
clicker._height = Stage.height;

however this causes the button to disapear from the stage, possibly down to 0x0 in size, as opposed to filling the available stage space. It's been a while since i worked with actionscript so it's probably something obvious, however i can't seem to spot what the problem is. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: As a further update, i resized the clicker button manually to 2000 pixels square which is fine for my current needs, though i am still curious why i've been unable to resize it dynamically. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener to the Stage:

var stageListener:Object = new Object();

stageListener.onResize = function() {
  clicker._width = Stage.width;
  clicker._height = Stage.height;
};

Stage.addListener(stageListener);